# fopen and empty file only at certain conditions

Tags: php

Goodmorning everyone.
I'm a bit stuck. Is there a way to fopen a file and empty it only under certain conditions?

What I want is:
 1. fopen( file ) --> flock --> read content of file
 2. If certain conditions are met, replace the content of the file
 3. unlock and fclose
The problem is:
`fopen (file, w+)` empties the file beforehand, so I can't read the content
`fopen (file, r+)` doesn't empty the file if I want to write to it

I have tried `ftruncate($fn,0)` in combination with `r+`, but that writes 'null' to the file
A workaround is to first read the filecontents and then open it. But I try to maintain a lock on the file from the moment of reading till I'm finished.
Anyone any ideas?

Edit:
The probleem seems the `fwrite`.
`ftruncate` clears the file, but `fwrite` adds a 'nul'. After 100 passes there are a hundred 'nul' in front of the data

```
$pt = "../path/file";  
$fn = lock_file($pt);  
$i = fread($fn,100);  
ftruncate($fn,0);  
fwrite($fn,"data");  
fflush($fn);  
flock($fn, LOCK_UN);  
fclose($fn);        

function lock_file($file){
$fn = fopen($file, "c+");  
$try=0;  
do{  
if($try>0){usleep(rand(1,10000));}
$try ++;
}
while(!flock($fn, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) and $try <= 300);
if($try>=300){return FALSE;}
return $fn;
}
```

Solved with `fseek($fn, 0);` 
Thanks!

Comment: 1. lock 2. read 3. write if necessary

Comment: What's the problem with calling `ftruncate` conditionally after you have read the file?

Comment: the problem is 3. fopen(r+) doesn't replcae the content, but adds

Comment: post the php code. the problem lies there because the algoritm should be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered 'c' or 'c+' modes instead of 'w'?

As [PHP manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'c' This may be useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see
> flock()) before attempting to modify the file, as using 'w' could
> truncate the file before the lock was obtained (if truncation is
> desired, ftruncate() can be used after the lock is requested).

*UPD:* As for the code posted above:

I have tried your code and saw nulls in beginning of the file.
However, when I added

```
 fseek($fn, 0);
```

before

```
 ftruncate($fn, 0);
```

everything went fine (without fseek, 0's are being appended)

Comment: I tried that. The problem is the emptying of the file.
w+ gives me a nice empty file
ftruncate($fn,0) somehow writes 'nul' to the file.

Comment: @Michel just tried that on my local machine. my tests make the file 0 size. are you sure you aren't writing to the file an empty variable? can you post the php code related to the question?

Comment: No it does not write nulls:

`<?php

file_put_contents('1.txt', 'some text');

var_dump(file_get_contents('1.txt'));


// will print string (9) "some text";

$f = fopen('1.txt', 'c+');

ftruncate($f, 0);

fclose($f);

var_dump(file_get_contents('1.txt'));

// will print string (0) "";
`

Comment: Add `fseek($fn, 0);` before `ftruncate($fn,0);` and everything will be ok

Answer (score 1):

```
fopen($fn, "a+");//opens file for appending, does not erase contents
fseek($fn, 0);//moves pointer to first position in file
```

After that you can call **ftruncate** if necessary.

Comment: it won't work. `fseek` doesn't work if file is opened in apend mode

Answer (score 0):

```
fopen($fn, 'c+'); // open the files in read / write, doesn't truncate on opening
fread($fn);
ftruncate($fn, 0);
```

Comment: I've tried that. The problem is the emptying of the file. w+ gives me a nice empty file, ftruncate($fn,0) somehow writes 'nul' to the file. Every time I pass the file trough the function, it adds a 'nul', leaving me with an ever growing file :-)